# Is a value of 60 seconds valid on date function?

Tags: date

man page for [date function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) shows that %S will display seconds value from 00 to 60.

> %S     second (00..60)

Is the documentation incorrect since the upper limit is actually 59? Otherwise it would indicate the existence of 61 seconds (starting from zero). How can the documentation be fixed in case it's wrong?

Comment: There are some years that need a leap second. Its insertion is decided upon irregularly by some consortium whose name just escapes me.

Comment: Maybe the International Earth Rotation Society? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is not wrong, there are [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) in some (irregular) years.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It seems I was not yet aware of the 27 leap seconds already inserted since 1972.